# VS code error when I open or try to save a file. Failed to save "fileName.java"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using VS code for a long time but recently it started showing this error when I try to save java files:

> Failed to save 'App.java': The content of the file is newer. Please compare your version with the file contents or overwrite the content of the file with your changes.

I tried to uninstall and install VS code and the extensions I had again but it did not work.

What else should I try? Thank you.

Comment: That message means that that file has been modified on disk different than your unsaved changes in VS Code. Did you edit that file outside of VS Code? Is the file stored in come context where something else might be modifying it such as OneDrive?

Comment: @user no only opened with notepad++ but not edited. The file is saved in my desktop.

Comment: try looking at the comparison and see what is on disk and see if there are any hints you can give us about why this might be happening. Unless this is a known bug (I tried a cursory google and didn't find any recent issue tickets), there's not much we can do without your machine (which only you have).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are using *Git*. If any option exists in the error message popup, you can choose to open the comparison file and decide which one to save.

It looks like you have a file conflict. The following setting is a possible solution:

> A save conflict can occur when a file is saved to disk that was changed by another program in the meantime. To prevent data loss, the user is asked to compare the changes in the editor with the version on disk. This setting should only be changed if you frequently encounter save conflict errors and may result in data loss if used without caution.

```json
    "files.saveConflictResolution": "overwriteFileOnDisk",
```

[image]

Comment: Adding this configuration enables real-time saving of files. `"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",`

Comment: I'd prefer to get down to the cause instead of bandaid it.